# Bootstrap CSS paths in Ruby on Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, themes

I have been trying to incorporate a Bootstrap theme into my Ruby on Rails project, I have succesfully installed Bootstrap onto my application, as the core Bootstrap classes work properly.

However, I cannot get it to load the CSS files associated with the bootstrap theme.

I have a partial for my header(layouts/_header.html.erb)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag  'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    <title>Youvents - Your life, Your Events</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="stylesheets/modern-business.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">-->

</head>
```

My assets/stylesheets/application.css

```
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 *= require bootstrap_and_overrides
```

And I have the modern-business.css file and all the css associated with them on the stylesheets folder.
However, the css fails to load when I run the server on my project.

Any idea or tips on how to fix this? And how does the Bootstrap css files work on Ruby on Rails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't load Bootstrap that way because of getting the asset pipeline to precompile properly in production.

I recommend using the [Bootstrap Sass gem](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass)

Then change your application.scss file to be a sass file: application.css.scss and load bootstrap like this:

```
// Load Bootstap and Font Awesome
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "font-awesome";
```

Then import all your own css modules as sass files, by giving them the .scss ending

For example, you'd have modern-business.scss in app/assets/stylesheets and load it in the application.css.scss like so:

```
@import "modern-business";
```

Comment: Ok, with your edit some of my questions were answered, but a final one remains. After I have my files renamed to .scss and imported on the application.scss, how do I use the on HTML? Do I keep using the old <a href=...> or is there a proper way to load them into an HTML file? @rlarcombe

Comment: Keep all your css files in app/assets/stylesheets
Use .scss ending, and then you can use all the cool SASS features, and load them as I have described in application.css.scss

The Rails Asset pipeline will load everything into your layout file when you call 

<%= stylesheet_link_tag  'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>

Comment: You don't ever need to load them into html with something like:

<link href="stylesheets/modern-business.css" rel="stylesheet">

the Rails Asset pipeline does it for you.

Check out: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Comment: Thanks @rlarcombe that was very helpful!

Comment: Just one more question, I've done everything as you mentioned and it ran everything smoothly. But as I import the css on to the file nothing changes on the page @rlarcombe

Comment: Are all your css files being loaded by the asset pipeline now?
If you are running your app in development mode, you should be able to go to:
http://localhost:3000/assets/application.css
in a browser, and see everything that is being loaded